# Cherry pick specific commits from development branch to production branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have two branches in the GIT GUI - Development and Production. When code is pushed onto development, in the CLI, I do git pull and then git merge and git push on the production branch.

If I have 3 commits on the CLI on development branch:

Commit1 - COMMIT HASH 1
Commit2 - COMMIT HASH 2
Commit3 - COMMIT HASH 3

How can I merge only Commit3 and Commit1 without using any additional branch?

Comment: As you said yourself, you can cherry pick. Unclear what the question is, or what "git pull and then git merge and git push on the production branch" even means.

Comment: There are multiple things you *can* do here. However, what you *should* do depends on what your `development` branch represents. If your normal workflow is to merge `development` into `production` when you release something, then you probably don't want to have the branches diverged permanently. Do you ever want to release commit2 sometime in the future?

Answer (score 4):

Via a terminal, `checkout` the branch you want to apply the commits to with

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

then simply use

```
git cherry-pick <commit1hash>
git cherry-pick <commit3hash>
```

If you want to be sure of what you're doing, `checkout` a new branch from the branch you want to apply the commits to so you can also use it as a sandbox without messing with the code of your production branch.